# Need help with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression like this:

```
string Size= "10.5M";
Match m = null;
if ((m = (new Regex(@"(\d)([MGTP%]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(Size))).Success)
{
    Size = m.Groups[1].ToString();
    if (m.Groups.Count > 1)
        SizeUnit = m.Groups[2].ToString(); // if not given, SizeUnit is percentage
}
```

But when I pass the value, Size shows as 10, and SizeUnit as "" instead of the expected Size = 10.5 and SizeUnit = M

Comment: This one might work: `(\d+\.\d+)([MGTP%]?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that your expression only currently matches on a digit and not on the decimal point and following digits.  This would be better I think

```
if ((m = (new Regex(@"(\d*\.?\d*)([MGTP%]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(Size))).Success)
{
   Size = m.Groups[1].ToString();
   if (m.Groups.Count > 1)
   SizeUnit = m.Groups[2].ToString(); // if not given, SizeUnit is percentage
}
```

which will match at least 0 or more digits followed by a single '.' followed by zero or more other digits.

Comment: You could use `*` instead of mixing `+` and `?`.

Comment: How do you know 10. is not valid and .5 is?

Comment: you're right, I could use *.  And I don't know what is valid and what isn't.  I assumed from the example it was a number that was going to be expected, but was just trying to point out what it would and wouldn't do.

Answer (score 4):

A `\d` doesn't match the '.'.  Use `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `\d` character class matches a digit character. To match a number with a fractional part, as in your example you will need to:

- Match more than one digit: apply the `+` quantifier to `\d`;
- Match the dot; since a dot has a special meaning (it matches any character), you need to escape it with a `\`;
- Match some more digits;
- Maybe make the dot and the fractional part optional, using the `?` (zero or one) and `*` (zero or more) quantifiers, respectively.

A regular expression like this one may suit your needs:

```
(\d+\.?\d*)([MGTP%]?)
```